OpenVPN Access Server Stuck on License Agreement
I followed the steps from the OpenVPN Access Server Portal to install OpenVPN Access Server on an Ubuntu Server 22 headless VM. After installing and automatically configuring the service, I went to log in at the admin portal and once I did I was presented with the license agreement, only when I click Agree it just refreshes the page and does nothing. So I went back and manually reconfigured the service with the /usr/local/openvpn_as/bin/ovpn-init tool and I was presented with the exact same issue. I looked through the logs and I couldn't find anything obvious there either, but I'll post them here if anyone thinks it will help.
Am I doing something wrong here or is my installation just broken? 

That's commercially provided software. You'll be best asking the company directly. I have nothing against it - it's just that you'll get better support from the provider

I’m voting to close this question because it relates to a closed proprietary application

@ChrisDavies There is a free tier for that software that is widely used though, and the support from the software publisher is far from ideal

https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=34263 maybe?

Did you read the license agreement?  Did you scroll all the way to the bottom?

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Yes and Yes

My thought was: I’ve seen dialogs like this that have a checkbox and a button.  Sometimes the checkbox is beside the button — but I don’t see one in your screenshot.  The other option is something at the bottom of the license agreement (i.e., of the scroll region) that you would need to hit before clicking “Agree”.

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' That was my first thought as well. I've checked for a checkbox in the agreement text, invisible somewhere on the page, I've tried incognito and different browsers, nothing seems to work.

I got normal OpenVPN to work and I gave up on solving this, but I'll leave this question for if anyone else has this problem and perhaps someone here finds a solution.
